# ReactJS - adding .then to function makes "this.state.searchText" invalid

Tags: reactjs, axios

Using axios, I am calling to an Mongo REST API. However, whenever I press the button which I have tied to it, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Object(...)(...) is undefined
onSearchButtonPressed
D:/foo/hello-world/src/RecipeBuilder.js:146

> 146 |     search_elastic(this.state.searchText).then({
      | ^  147 | 
  148 |     })
  149 |
```

Why is this happening? If I call search_elastic without appending `then`, it seems to work, however no data is returned. Even more interesting, if I remove encapsulation of the `search_elastic` method and directly insert the `axios.get` code block into the `onSearchButtonPressed()` method, there is no issue.

My class is set up like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {search_elastic, shell} from './Backend.js'

class RecipeBuilder extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: '',
            term: '',
            editDisabled: false,
            ingredients: [],
            candidates: [],
            searchText: '',
            searchResults: []
        }
        this.onSearchTextChange = this.onSearchTextChange.bind(this)
        this.onSearchButtonPressed = this.onSearchButtonPressed.bind(this)
    }
    onSearchTextChange(filterText) {
        console.log({filterText})
        this.setState({
            searchText: filterText
        });
    }
    onSearchButtonPressed() {
        search_elastic(this.state.searchText).then(data => {
            //ideally would like to add data from this method to the RecipeBuilder state

        })
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-12">
                    <SearchBar
                      searchText={this.state.searchText}
                      onSearchTextChange={this.onSearchTextChange}
                      />
                      <button onClick={this.onSearchButtonPressed}>Search</button>
            </div>
            )
    }
}
export default RecipeBuilder
```

The `SearchBar` component is set up as such:

```
class SearchBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSearchTextChange = this.handleSearchTextChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleSearchTextChange(e) {
        this.props.onSearchTextChange(e.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <form>
                <input
                 type="text"
                 placeholder="Search..."
                 value={this.props.searchText}
                 onChange={this.handleSearchTextChange}
                />
            </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And the `Backend.js` can be seen here:

```
import axios from 'axios'


export const search_elastic = term => {
    axios
        .get(`api/search/${term}`, {
            headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
            return response
        })
}

export const shell = () => {
    console.log("In shell")

}
```

Working revision of `onSearchButtonPressed()` (however I have no clue why):

```
    onSearchButtonPressed() {
        axios.get(`api/search/${this.state.searchText}`, {
                headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }
            }).then((response) => {
                //console.log(response)
                if (response != null) { 
                    var data = response["data"]
                    var result = data["result"]
                    var hitsObj = result["hits"]
                    var hitsArray = hitsObj["hits"]
                    this.setState({searchResults: [...hitsArray]})
                    console.log(this.state.searchResults)
                }
                return response
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `search_elastic` function doesn't return anything. It needs to return the promise from `axios.get()`.

```js
// either *return* axios.get or remove the curlies for an implicit arrow function return
export const search_elastic = term => {
  return axios
    .get(`api/search/${term}`, {
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
      return response
    })
}
```